# org.hibernate.AnnotationException:No identifier specified for entity with XML Mapping

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm working on a JPA program and had to write annotations for one class via xml-mapping. I wrote my model class like that:

```java
ppackage model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
public class Reservierung {
    public Reservierung(Date datum, int praemienMeilenBonus, int preis, StatusInfo status, Zug zug, Strecke strecke, Benutzer benutzer, Zahlung zahlung) {
        this.datum = datum;
        this.praemienMeilenBonus = praemienMeilenBonus;
        this.preis = preis;
        this.status = status;
        this.zug = zug;
        this.strecke = strecke;
        this.benutzer = benutzer;
        this.zahlung = zahlung;
    }

    private Long ID;

    private Date datum;

    private int praemienMeilenBonus = 15;

    private int preis = 150;

    private StatusInfo status;
    private Zug zug;
    private Strecke strecke;
    private Benutzer benutzer;
    private Zahlung zahlung;

    public Date getDatum() {
        return datum;
    }

    public void setDatum(Date datum) {
        this.datum = datum;
    }

    public int getPraemienMeilenBonus() {
        return praemienMeilenBonus;
    }

    public void setPraemienMeilenBonus(int praemienMeilenBonus) {
        this.praemienMeilenBonus = praemienMeilenBonus;
    }

    public int getPreis() {
        return preis;
    }

    public void setPreis(int preis) {
        this.preis = preis;
    }

    public StatusInfo getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(StatusInfo status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Zug getZug() {
        return zug;
    }

    public void setZug(Zug zug) {
        this.zug = zug;
    }

    public Strecke getStrecke() {
        return strecke;
    }

    public void setStrecke(Strecke strecke) {
        this.strecke = strecke;
    }

    public Benutzer getBenutzer() {
        return benutzer;
    }

    public void setBenutzer(Benutzer benutzer) {
        this.benutzer = benutzer;
    }

    public Zahlung getZahlung() {
        return zahlung;
    }

    public void setZahlung(Zahlung zahlung) {
        this.zahlung = zahlung;
    }

    public Long getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public void setID(Long ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }
}
```

and after that I created the xml mapping file that I named orm:

```xml
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
        version="2.0">
    <named-query name="Reservierung.findAll">
        <query>SELECT b FROM model.Reservierung b</query>
    </named-query>
    <entity name="Reservierung" class="model.Reservierung" >
        <table name="Reservierung" />
        <attributes>
            <id name="ID">
                <generated-value strategy="AUTO" />
            </id>
            <basic name="datum" />
            <basic name="praemienMeilenBonus" />
            <basic name="preis" />
            <basic name="StatusInfo" />

            <one-to-one name="strecke" />
            <one-to-one name="zug"/>
            <one-to-one name="benutzer"/>
            <transient name="zahlung"/>
        </attributes>
    </entity>
</entity-mappings>
```

finnaly I added the orm.xml and all the other files in my persistence.xml, which looks now like this

```xml
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
  version="2.1">

  <persistence-unit name="westbahn">
      <description> Hibernate JPA Configuration Example</description>
      <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

      <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>

      <class>model.Bahnhof</class>
      <class>model.Benutzer</class>
      <class>model.Reservierung</class>
      <class>model.Einzelticket</class>
      <class>model.Preisstaffelung</class>
      <class>model.Sonderangebot</class>
      <class>model.Strecke</class>
      <class>model.Ticket</class>
      <class>model.Zeitkarte</class>
      <class>model.Zug</class>
      <class>model.Reservierung</class>

        <properties>
    <!--
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/westbahn?serverTimezone=UTC" />
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="westbahnUser" />
          <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="westbahnPassword" />
    -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"    value="jdbc:h2:file:./db/testing" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <!--<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>-->
        </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Till now I tried to see if the names where spelled wrong, if my class had some attributes that I didn't account for and also tried to change the name and finally added access="field" to the entity tag, but if I do so, I get another exception on top of the first one: **org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to load class defined in XML: model.Reservierung**

Where did I do wrong?

edit:
Before the new orm.xml I had different mapping file named  Reservierung.hbm.xml

```xml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="model.Reservierung" table="Reservierung">
        <meta attribute = "class-description">
            This class contains the reservations
        </meta>

        <id name = "ID" type = "long" column = "ID">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>

        <property name = "datum" column = "datum" type = "date"> </property>
        <property name = "praemienMeilenBonus" column = "praemienMeilenBonus"> </property>
        <property name = "preis" column = "preis"> </property>
        <property name = "status" column = "status">
            <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">model.StatusInfo</param>
            </type>
        </property>
        <one-to-one name="strecke" />
        <one-to-one name="zug"/>
        <one-to-one name="benutzer"/>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I wasn't happy with it, so I trashed it and started from scratch with the orm.xml file

edit: what I did:
I made a constructor + getter and setter in all classes and now the exception changed to this:

```java
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass (org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass and org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.bind(PropertyBinder.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makePropertyValueAndBind(PropertyBinder.java:205)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:2283)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:976)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:803)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:903)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:934)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:56)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:79)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:47)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:64)
```

Comment: 1) You can remove  <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file> because this is the default. 2) you also can remove <class>model.Reservierung</class> Then try again

Comment: sadly doing so didn't really improve anything.

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace

Comment: Just added it to the post. I also did changed some stuff, added getter setters for every attribute + constructor for every class that is going to be saved.

Comment: But this is something completely different! Do you have inheritance in the other Entities?